# Converting Japanese Imperial date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date-conversion

I need to convert Japanese dates (based on the imperial era) to Gregorian ones. That is, 平成27年5月21日 is May 21th, 2015. Converting the other way round shows that format string "EEYY" gives the year 平成27. However, when I try

```
TO_DATE('平成27年5月21日', 'EEYY年MM月DD日', 'NLS_CALENDAR=''JAPANESE IMPERIAL''')
```

I get the error message "not a valid era". But Oracle's own conversion and other sources confirm that it is indeed valid. Every googlable source gives the solution as "provide a valid era" - not very helpful!

Comment: What's your Oracle version?

Comment: It's not that you're missing a 0 in front of the 5 is it? Did you mean '平成27年05月21日'

Comment: Or a character set problem? Oracle's expecting JA16EUC, apparently.

Comment: No, the character set is probably OK. If I omit the "era" part and use "YY" (but the other japanese separators), I get today's date from '27年5月26日'. The month is not the problem, it isn't supposed to be zero padded.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved, and I blame my short acquaintance span with Oracle for not getting it sooner. (A workmate did).

```
NLS_LANG = JAPANESE_JAPAN.AL32UTF8
```

had to be set as environment variable. David Aldridge was indeed on the right track, and your solution might have worked equally well.
I was fooled by the fact that the other Japanese characters seemed to work, but they did not: they were just separators which didn't need to be interpreted in any way - but the "era" part did,